# inserting blank row/cell from datatable into database in C#.NET

Tags: c#

I am reading data table and trying to insert into database. Now, I have few rows/cell whose is null or empty.

I want to insert those row properly into database.

Can anyone help me out or provide me simple program.

Thanks,
Rushabh Shah.

Comment: Please provide some more information or code so we can help you with your exact issue.

Comment: I am reading row from data table and trying to insert those row into database. Now, I have few cell in row whose value is null or empty.

I want to insert those row properly into database.

Answer (score 1):

Just set any value you want to be "blank" to [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx), which "Represents a nonexistent value".

Comment: I am reading row from data table and trying to insert those row into database. Now, I have few cell in row whose value is null or empty.

I need to assign those cell value to be DBNull.Value or what.

Comment: @Rushabh: If they're in a DataTable, they're probably already set to DBNull.Value.  In that case, you can just copy them across into your db.  Without showing us actual code that is failing, though, it's difficult to know exactly how to help...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is the situation. I have 6 columns in datatable and out of 6 only 2 columns consist value. Now, I am reading one rows and trying to insert into my database. At time of inserting I getting error that blank field can't be insert.

Comment: @Rushabh are those columns nullable in database?

Comment: @Lav: All those columns can except nullable value.